# object reference not set to instance of an object inside Binding List c#

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

I am trying to read the fields in an Excel document and store the values into respective variables using Binding List and export it to Sql Server 2008 Database

Following is the code which I Found Online

public void csv()
        {

```
        try
        {
            MyApp = new Excel.Application();
            MyApp.Visible = false;
            OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
            ofd.FileName = "";
            ofd.ShowDialog();
            MyBook = MyApp.Workbooks.Open(ofd.FileName);
            MySheet = (Excel.Worksheet)MyBook.Sheets[1]; // Explicit cast is not required here
            var lastRow = MySheet.Cells.SpecialCells(Excel.XlCellType.xlCellTypeLastCell).Row;


            BindingList<ExportExcel> EmpList = new BindingList<ExportExcel>();

            for (int index = 2; index <= lastRow; index++)
            {

                System.Array MyValues = (System.Array)MySheet.get_Range("A" + index.ToString(), "G" + index.ToString()).Cells.Value;

                EmpList.Add(new ExportExcel
                {
                    PersonName = MyValues.GetValue(1, 1).ToString(),
                    Product = MyValues.GetValue(1, 2).ToString(),
                    StartDate = Convert.ToDateTime(MyValues.GetValue(1, 3).ToString()),
                    ExpiresOn = Convert.ToDateTime(MyValues.GetValue(1, 4).ToString()),
                    DaysIssued = MyValues.GetValue(1, 5).ToString(),
                    TrialsIssued = MyValues.GetValue(1, 6).ToString(),
                    Contact = MyValues.GetValue(1, 7).ToString()
                });

                query = "EXEC dbo.proc_ImportExcel'" + PersonName + "', '" + Product + "','" + StartDate + "','" + DaysIssued + "','" + ExpiresOn + "','" + TrialsIssued + "','" + Contact + "'";
            }

            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(query, con);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

I am getting proper values in the line **PersonName = MyValues.GetValue(1, 1).ToString(),** and the values are not getting stored in variable personName whereas the the values are shown in line  **MyValues.GetValue(1, 1).ToString()**,I am getting an error  object reference not set to instance of an object.

Can anyone help me to solve this issue.

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: `MyValues` might be null.

Comment: @Bharadwaj I am getting values in MyValues but PersonName is showing null.I variables that will be assigned these values